# PHP - Sending Email HTML/Plain Text - Syntax Error?

Tags: php, html, email, text, syntax-error

I am trying to implement a simple sendEmails function that sends HTML if possible, if not it sends plain text. However, I am getting a syntax error in the file for some reason, even though if I pass it through an online validator, such as phpcodechecker, it doesn't come up with any problems.

The exact error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs..\func.php on line 83

Note: I have only implemented the sendEmails function, which broke it.

My code

```
<?php

    //Input: Email | Output: Boolean for Domain Existence (such as @yahoo.com) [TESTED]
    function domainExists($email, $record = 'MX'){
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
        return checkdnsrr($domain, $record);
    }

    function sendEmails($to, $type, $link){
        switch($type){
            case "register":
                if(strlen($link)>0) $authenticationLink = $link;
                else throwError("Email Failed",1);
                //Send Email
                $subject = "Thank You For Registering";
                $boundaryHash = md5(date('r',time()));
                $headers = "From: admin@....com";
                $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$boundaryHash."\"";
                ob_start();
                ?>
                    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $boundaryHash; ?> 
                    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
                    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

                    Thank you for registering with ...! 
                    We hope you enjoy our service! To get started, please authenticate your account by copying and pasting the following link:
                    <?php echo $authenticationLink; ?>

                    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $boundaryHash; ?> 
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
                    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

                    <h2>Thank You For Registering!</h2>
                    <p>Thank you for registering with ...!</p>

                    <p>We hope you enjoy our service! To get started, please authenticate your account with the following link:</p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $authenticationLink; ?>">Click to Authenticate</a>

                    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $boundaryHash; ?>--
                <?
                $message = ob_get_clean();
                $mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        return;
    }

    //isEscaped(String, Con):boolean, [TESTED]
    function isEscaped($str, $con){
        return (mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $str) === $str);
    }


    //Type: | 0: Unknown Error | 1:  | 2: DB Error | 3: Security Issue - Unescaped |
    //String: | 'Fatal' | 'NonFatal' | 'Trivial' | Otherwise String will be output
    //[TESTED]
    function throwError($str, $type){
        //Making sure parameters are valid
        $t = (int)$type; 
        $s = (string)$str;  

        //Shorthand to auto output general errors
        switch ($s){ 
            case 'Fatal': 
                $s = "FATAL ERROR: Please contact the administrator immediately!"; 
                break;
            case 'NonFatal':
                $s = "ERROR: Please contact the administrator!";
                break;
            case 'Trivial':
                $s = "Unexpected Error: Please go back and try again!";
                break;
        }

        echo "<p class='errorspan'>".$s.": ".$t."</p>";
        exit($t);
    }?>
```

Comment: Make sure open tags are "ON", you have `<? $message = ob_get_clean();` which may be one of the things at play.

Comment: Plus `unexpected end of file` means you have a missing closing brace somewhere or an opening brace too many, which may be coming from what is evidently an included file. There's only 79 lines in your posted code, out of 83.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the '<?', I guess I've been staring at it too long(now it works!)... I did check all of the braces before asking though. Thank you so much!

Comment: So the problem was that then, yes?

Comment: I can put in an answer that way you'll have a clean record instead of deleting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure open tags are "ON", you have `<? $message = ob_get_clean();` which may be one of the things at play.

Change it to:

```
<?php $message = ob_get_clean();
```

Plus, `unexpected end of file` means you have a missing closing brace somewhere or an opening brace too many, which may be coming from what is evidently an included file.

There's only 79 lines in your posted code, out of 83.